# Find members email addresses of a mail group using Outlook/Office 365 REST API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I want to get all the members of a mail group using Outlook/Office 365 REST API.

For example: name: #allusers email: allusers@xyz.com

I want list down all the members of the #allusers group.

What is the API call would do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "Get member objects" call of a group. (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_getmemberobjects).

If you are new to the Microsoft Graph API, I recommend that you check out the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) to get a feel for the structure of the objects that you can retrieve and manipulate using the API.

In the demo tentant of the Graph Explorer, for example, this URL will return group members of one group:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/22be6ccb-15a5-459f-94ac-d1393bdd9e66/members

Comment: I got the error. "This query requires additional permissions. If you are an administrator, you can click here to grant them on behalf of your entire organization."  

I can able to give user consent only for my app. It looks like need to give admin consent for accessing groups. I register my app using Outlook ApI app registration tool.

Comment: Is there any way in app registration site to specify admin consent for my app? or can i specify admin related scopes dynamically from my code like use related scope?

Comment: We have 2 registration sites.  If you are using the Azure Portal, you can configure the permissions that your app needs, and then in that experience click the "Grant Permissions" button to grant permissions in your tenant (if you are an admin in your tenant).  Alternatively, if you are using the other registration portal (apps.dev.microsoft.com), follow these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#admin-restricted-scopes

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this that is we can get the Group ID from the group mail address.using

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=mail+eq+'abc@xyz.com

By next using the ID we can get the group user details (mail) using

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/91234b-43c6-4435-ac69-02b8e0cc6570/members?$select=mail,displayName

But here has a problem that is I don`t know how to get the next page of the result :-(

If you know the solution for find the next page kindly let me know!

Comment: If I use the API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups it returns an empty list to me, but I am having groups in my account! Any idea?